# What is the usefulness of the Flow coverage score?

Tags: javascript, types, code-coverage, flowtype, typechecking

I don't understand what the Flow coverage score indicates. Flow will not report any errors against a file, but then give it a low coverage score. I have a file that Flow tells me is error free, yet I only have 28% coverage. Does it not count its own inference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coverage score indicates what % of types have flow type annotations.

These are not errors (although potential ones), but flow lacks some informations to check 100% of your types.

Comment: In other words, if I have a low coverage score, but no errors, Flow is just able to infer all unannotated types?

Answer (score 2):

The Flow coverage score is used to describe the degree to which the source code of your app is type-checked. **Type-checking** is the process during which Flow verifies and enforces that the type of a construct (constant, boolean, number, variable, array, object, function, class) matches an invariant that you’ve specified.

So, **an app with a high Flow coverage has more of its source code type-checked**, which suggests **it has a lower chance of containing undetected software bugs** (unhandled types, typographical errors in nested objects) compared to a program with a low Flow coverage.

If your app has a Flow coverage score of 100%, you can also assume that **you can refactor your code safely**, and even trust your editor to perform some refactoring tasks by itself, eg. renaming the property of an object across several files (in VSCode, right click > Rename Symbol).